# Why does the popstate event not fire?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-history, popstate

I am trying to understand the `popstate` event in JavaScript and for that I created this simple AJAX-based navigation website.

Here's `home.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        <a href="about.html">About</a>
    </header>

    <div id="main">
        <h1>Home Page</h1>
        <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus eligendi suscipit aliquid. Mollitia ratione impedit ab, dicta reprehenderit veniam nam facere ipsam vel minus doloribus officia, odit dolorum alias error.</p>
    </div>
    <script src="nav.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's `about.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>About Us</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        <a href="about.html">About</a>
    </header>

    <div id="main">
        <h1>About</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto placeat ipsam nam nobis exercitationem voluptatibus, officia impedit. Dolore, esse dignissimos enim porro aspernatur sit aperiam asperiores, maiores, hic velit quod.</p>
    </div>
    <script src="nav.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the script `nav.js`:

```
// implementing ajax-based navigation
var main = document.getElementById('main');

function makeRequest(url, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.responseType = 'document';
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            callback(this);
        }
    }
    xhr.send();
}

window.onclick = function(e) {
    if (e.target.href != window.location.href) {
        history.pushState(null, '', e.target.href);
    }

    makeRequest(e.target.href, function(xhr) {
        document.title = xhr.responseXML.title;
        main.innerHTML = xhr.responseXML.getElementById('main').innerHTML;
    });
    e.preventDefault();

    window.onpopstate = function(e) {
        console.log('The popstate event has fired')
        makeRequest(window.location.href, function(xhr) {
            main.innerHTML = xhr.responseXML.getElementById('main').innerHTML;
        });
    }
}
```

The problem I am facing is detailed as follows:

1. I go to a new tab and open up the document `index.html`. This is the first entry in the tab's history.
2. On this page, I click the link pointing to `about.html`. As a result, the `window.onclick` handler gets fired and ultimately, using AJAX, the document `about.html` gets dynamically displayed. The browser's title also gets changed, as well as the URL (which happens due to `history.pushState()`).
3. Now I go back (using the back button of the browser), the URL changes to `index.html`, and consequently the `popstate` event fires on `window`. Here, I reload the contents of `index.html` into the current document and everything works fine.
4. I go back, which takes me to the home page of Google Chrome (the start of every new tab).
5. Now, I go forward. This takes me to the document `index.html`. What is displayed on the browser are the contents of `index.html`. So uptil this point, everything is working fine.
6. I go forward again. The browser's URL changes to `about.html` and its title as well. However, this time, **the `popstate` event doesn't fire**. The URL has changed to a location which was set earlier on using `history.pushState()` so I expect the `popstate` event to fire. However, it doesn't.

**What is the reason for the `popstate` event not firing on the last forward step?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `window.onpopstate = function(e) {` block should be outside the  `window.onclick = function(e) {` block.